# python phanthomjs is not working with nohup

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm running selenium  using phanthomjs, the script is running perfectly if when I trigger it as:

```
python my_script.py
```

But when I try to using nohup:

```
nohup python my_script.py &
```

I got the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service phantomjs unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 8
```

Comment: How about running it in screen or tmux?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late but I just met similar error just with another code and I've found a solution. So, when you run nohup your program's output is redirected to nohup.out, and the file for me was like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
me/fanar/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running

  File "main.py", line 51, in <module>
    Work()
  File "main.py", line 41, in Work
    TakeImage() # start o 16
  File "main.py", line 9, in TakeImage
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
  File "/home/fanar/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/fanar/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 96, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/fanar/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service phantomjs unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

The workaround was to go to the

```
.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py
```

and comment out line

```
self.assert_process_still_running()
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the parameters works for me:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = '/usr/lib/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs')
```