# Google Chrome and selenium webdriver not working as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-chrome, selenium

I'm attempting to run a test via Google Chrome using `selenium` and `Python 2.7.x`. While doing so I have gotten the following error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

The full traceback for this error message looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/google_search/search.py", line 347, in parse_search_results
    browser_type=web_browser)
  File "/home/google_search/search.py", line 218, in get_urls
    browser = config_browser(proxy=proxy, agent=user_agent)
  File "/home/google_search/search.py", line 154, in config_browser
    chrome_options=options, service_args=["--verbose"], service_log_path=CHROME_FILE_LOG
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 96, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

---

My driver version: `ChromeDriver 2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4`
My browser version: `Google Chrome 62.0.3202.62`
My selenium version: `selenium (3.5.0)`

---

How this is being run:

```
def config_browser(user_agent=None, proxy=None)
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    if user_agent is not None:
        options.add_argument("--user-agent={}".format(user_agent))
    if proxy is not None:
        options.add_argument("--proxy-server={}".format(proxy))
    profile = webdriver.Chrome(
        chrome_options=options, service_args=["--verbose"], service_log_path=CHROME_FILE_LOG
    )
    return profile
```

When I run it, I am unable to get the log because it exits before anything happens. The chromedriver is executable in my path (used `chmod a+x /usr/bin/chromedriver`) at the following location: `/usr/bin/chromedriver`.

I've done some research and my current chromedriver version supports 60-62, it could be that my version is above 62, but that seems illogical. What is the issue here and how can I fix this problem?

---

It is probably worth mentioning that I am hiding the browser using `pyvirtualdisplay` it is being started before the call to the function that configures the browser itself:

```
browser_display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
browser_display.start()
browser = config_browser(proxy=proxy, agent=user_agent)
```

---

Edit:

As mentioned in the comments I attempted to update my `selenium` version to `3.6.0` it still produces the same error. So I uninstalled `google-chrome-stable` and went with the pre-installed `chromium-browser` version: `Chromium 61.0.3163.100 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 17.04`. I am still receiving the exact same error with the new guidelines:

Guidelines:

Chromium browser: `Chromium 61.0.3163.100 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 17.04`
Selenium version: `3.6.0`

```
WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

Comment: What is your version of selenium?

Comment: @DurdenP see the newest edit, selenium is `3.5.0`

Comment: Update Selenium to 3.6 and try again. **Or**, downgrade Chrome and try again.

Comment: @SiKing how can you downgrade Chrome? Isn’t there a set version for `apt-get`?

Comment: https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/pm/google-chrome-stable However, updating Selenium to match your browser version is usually the more desirable option.

Comment: @SiKing hey, thank you for the advice, I updated selenium and am still receiving the same error, new selenium version: `Successfully installed selenium-3.6.0` and the same version of Google Chrome. Any other ideas?

Comment: "It is probably worth mentioning that I am hiding the browser" - if you eliminate this variable, do you still see the problem? Are you aware of Chrome-headless mode?

Comment: @SiKing Let me try, I don't think the display variable using `Xvfb` should have any effect on the driver, but let's find out.

Comment: @SiKing `WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1` commented out the call to `pyvirtualdisplay` and I get the same error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46131482/3124333 ? At this point I think it might be a Python issue, which I am not familiar with. So other than this, I am out of ideas.

Comment: @SiKing Yeah I already tried that one as well before I asked the question, got the same error. I'm thinking it's a driver problem, maybe if I use a different driver version it will work, thank you for your help

Comment: I'm still having this issue, does anybody have any solutions?

Comment: So nobody knows the cause or solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I used Firefox instead.

```
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
# do whatever you want with the profile
browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
return browser
```

Apparently there is absolutely no knowledge of this problem anywhere (not even on the Github), so I just said forget Chrome and stuck with Firefox because it actually works.